# Выполнение многострочного INSERT-запроса приводит к 502 ошибке

Tags: php, foreach, циклы, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Осуществляю xml-парсинг с помощью `simplexml`. Есть блок товаров, примерно 37 000 товаров. Нужно записать в базу MySQL. Что бы не делать 37000 запросов к базе создаю строку типа

```
INSERT INTO tbl (*,*,*) VALUES (***), (***), ..., (***)
```

Цикл идет долго и от сервера получаю ответ `502 Bad Gateway`. При этом заливаются в базу примерно 28 000 товаров. Пробовал разбивать на части и заливать по 100 при каждом запросе, то же самое (заливает тоже мало). Можно как то отправить заголовок браузеру, чтобы он "подождал еще"? Или как то по другому решить проблему?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `php`-скрипте дописать в начало:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Это позволит выполняться скрипту долго.

Возможно такое что не хватает памяти на выполнение операции. Попробуйте увеличить лимит в `php.ini`:

```
memory_limit 1024M
```

Посмотрите что в логах написано.

С браузером тут два варианта:

1. Если на фронтенде стоит `nginx`, проксирующий запросы на `apache`, то он будет ждать 60 секунд (по умолчанию, если другое не определено конфигом), после чего разорвет соединение и отдаст браузеру `Gateway Timedout`. Но при этом работа скрипта не будет прервана и скрипт выполниться полностью.
2. Если на фронтенде стоит `apache`, то браузер будет ждать столько сколько будет выполняться скрипт.

В вашем случае, скорее всего, не хватает памяти для выполнения скрипта. Сам с таким сталкивался, когда похожим образом пытался засунуть в БД кучу записей. Сообщения о нехватке памяти попадают в `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (либо другой, определенный виртуальным хостом).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, если операцию долгая, лучше заливать в фоне cli-скриптом. А на фронтэнде посылать запросы к серверу, чтобы проверять лишь статус задачи.

И, посмотрите текст ошибки, он о многом скажет.